# DirectWebRemoting errors

Tags: dwr

I am supporting an application that has some DWR components. Whenever there is a server error i get a javascript alert that simply says '**error**'.

Does anyone know where this might be configured and if there is a way to disable this. Id rather it silently fail at whatever then do this very distracting message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DWR exception handlers in the positions wherever there is a chance for run time errors.

Use try catch mechanism and printstacktrace() in catch block. It works for me!